# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Actually I am trying to plot a count plot for my numpy array with the shape of (5216,1) by using seaborn library. When I try like this

```
train_y.shape
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=train_y)
```

But It throughs out the like this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-44c4401caea5> in <module>
    1 sns.set(style="darkgrid")
----> 2 ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=train_y)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in countplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
 3553                           estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed,
 3554                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 3555                           errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
 3556 
 3557     plotter.value_label = "count"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
 1613         """Initialize the plotter."""
 1614         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
-> 1615                                  order, hue_order, units)
 1616         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
 1617         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot, seed)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
  141             # See if we need to get variables from `data`
  142             if data is not None:
--> 143                 x = data.get(x, x)
  144                 y = data.get(y, y)
  145                 hue = data.get(hue, hue)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'
```

anyone please help me to solve this error

Comment: what do you want the first line to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `numpy` array instead of a `pandas.Dataframe`, you can simply pass the array as either the `x` or `y` argument to `countplot`.

E.g.

```
import numpy
import seaborn

data = numpy.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
ax = seaborn.countplot(x=data)
```

This does not seem to work with multidimensional arrays. Without knowing more about what data you are plotting, it is hard to say for sure how to produce the particular plot you want. However, since your array has only length 1 in the second dimension, how about simply reshaping the array to be one dimensional?

E.g.

```
train_y.shape = len(train_y)
ax = sns.countplot(x=train_y)
```

As an aside, it is preferred to use `pandas.DataFrames` instead of `numpy.arrays`. The examples in the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), which I assume you have tried to emulate here, use `DataFrames`. You can convert your array into a `DataFrame`, and specify the name of the variable you will later plot.

E.g.

```
import numpy
import seaborn as sns
import pandas

data = numpy.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2])
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["variable"])
```

Here, `"variable"` is the name of a column in the `df` 'table'. Then when you plot with `countplot`, specify this column as the argument to `x`.

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="variable", data=df)
```

Comment: Thank you, Actually I get some clear intuition from your answer. If we use array to plot a count plot we want to give our input shape as `(n, )`  or we will convert our numpy array as pandas data frame as you mentioned above.